multiple API calls because component re render issue
I have 2 components Files (parent) and NoteList (child)
There is a list of files for example I've taken 1 to 5 numbers in files variable it means it renders 5 cards and each card have toggle button
NOTE: I need to open the previously opened or expanded cards to be open as it is, it means i clicked 1st card and after that clicked on 2nd card so there is no auto collapse i don't need to collapse auto previously opened card
In the <NoteList /> component i am calling the API to fetch the notes according to the folder id which i've passed using useEffect
PROBLEM
When i click to toggle/open the 1st folder/card then all the notes data is fetched using the NoteList component but after that when i am clicking to the 2nd folder means 2nd card then 2 APIs called (1st folder API and 2nd folder API), same for if i opened or expanded the 10 folders and try to open the 11th card then 11 APIs are called. it is useless how can i fix this issue???
Files.js
const files = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; // example
const [openFolderDetails, setOpenFolderDetails] = useState([]);

const toggleBtn = (folder) => {
  if (openFolderDetails.includes(folder)) {
    setOpenFolderDetails(
      openFolderDetails.filter((tempFolder) => tempFolder !== folder),
    );
  } else {
    setOpenFolderDetails([...openFolderDetails, folder]);
  }
};

return (
  <>
    {files.map((el,i) => {
      return (
        <Fragment key={i}>
          <div> Folder {el} </div>
          <button onClick={() => toggleBtn(el)}>Open notes</button>

          {
            openFolderDetails?.includes(el) && (
              <NotesList folder={el} {...props} />
            ) //props passed according to the need
          }
        </Fragment>
      );
    })}
  </>
);

NotesList component:

const NotesList = ({folder}) => {

useEffect(()=>{
    if(folder){
      // call API to fetch all the notes according to the folder id and store data into the state
    }
},[folder])

   return <>
     {
     // listed all data of notes
  }
</>


}

export default NotesList


Expected output:
call the single API for when I click to open the specific folder, not call all the folders API again

Are you ignoring warning about missing key props?

No, i used key prop but just i am giving the basic overview what i had implemented.. the real error is redundant API call.

Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre].

Are you having any dependencies inside the useEffect body forgot to include in the dependency array? I tried your simplified example and don't see any redundant call.

Thanks @RickyMo i checked your example and it is working fine, in mine case i have some other dependencies so i have to check and report you back
